# Matching Sets in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am running a query similar to below:

`` `SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1',`tags`) OR FIND_IN_SET('2',`tags`)... ``

Is there a simpler way to run a query to say if any number in a set matches any number in another set?

For example, I'd like to do something like this:

`` `SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE MATCH_ANY_IN_SET('1,2,7,34,45',`tags`) ``

Comment: Create a separate table of thing:tag relations: that is, pairs of `(thing_id, tag_id)`.

Comment: @eggyal - Is there a way to do that without a procedure?

Comment: See my answer below for a more complete description of what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Having a delimited list of "tags" in a string field is not a very good use of a relational database management system like MySQL.

It'd be much more sensible to create a separate table, let's call it `ThingTags`, which relate things in your existing table to their tags:

```
CREATE TABLE ThingTags (
  ThingID INT NOT NULL,
  TagID   INT NOT NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY (ThingID) REFERENCES `table` (ID)
);
```

The `FOREIGN KEY` constraint tells MySQL that records can only exist in `ThingTags` if there is a corresponding entry in `table` (where `ThingTags.ThingID = table.ID`).

There would therefore be multiple records in this table for each "thing":

```
INSERT INTO ThingTags VALUES (1,1), (1,7), (1,45), (2,1), (2,34);
```

Your query would then look something like this:

```
SELECT `table`.*
FROM   `table` JOIN `ThingTags` ON `ThingTags`.`ThingID` = `table`.`ID`
WHERE  `ThingTags`.`TagID` IN (1,2,7,34,45);
```